# How to insert name filed in the query, but to the table to pass the corresponding id of that name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
genres_table:                     bands_table:

genre_id | genre_name            band_id | genre_id | band_name
   1     |   Rock                   1    |    8     | Blink 182
   3     |   Jazz                   3    |    1     | Foo Fighters
   8     |   Punk                   4    |    1     | RHCP
```

Genre_id is a foreign key in `bands_table` taken from genre_id in `genres_table`.

I would like to insert new rows to `bands_table`, currently I do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO bands_table (genre_id, band_name) VALUES(1, "Rammstein") - band_id column is auto-incremented by phpmyadmin, so I don't insert it.
```

However, I would like to insert **not genre_id** and band_name, but **genre_name** and band_name.
But, I need to keep genre_id in the table since it's connected by a FK and it needs to be so.

How can I achieve this? So when I insert ("Rock", "Rammstein") it will automatically compare Rock to `gender_id = 1` , and will insert instead of "Rock", 1 to gender_id.

Comment: MySql != Sql Server, please fix your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert using a `select` query:

```
insert into bands_table (genre_id, band_name)
select genre_id, 'Rammstein'
from genres_table
where genre_name = 'Rock';
```

Note, string literals should be specified with single quotes.

Comment: Thank you @Stu that worked well! Great solution

Answer (score 0):

in case you just want to give the genre_name and band_name and rest the query must understand to first insert the genre_name and then the band_name with the foreign key from the table genres_table..

you can manage the duplication by transaction lock..

```
INSERT INTO genres_table(genre_name) VALUES ('genre_name'); 
SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO bands_table(band_name,genre_id) VALUES ('band_name',@last_id_in_table1);
```